# How to Separate an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array object like this

```
      dta: [
        {
           amt: "200000",
           dat: "2016-10-14 10:41:20 am",
           grt: "GRT",
           uid:"example123"
        },
        {
           amt: "300000",
           dat: "2016-10-14 10:41:20 am",
           grt: "RPD",
           uid:"example123"
        }]
```

and I wish to split this array in two arrays based on the based on the `grt:`

I tried this but it starts the secong array index from 1.

```
function seperate(data) {
console.log(data)
for (var i = 0; i < data.dta.length; i++) {
       if (data.dta[i].grt === 'GRT') {
            owing[i] = data.dta[i];
       } else {
            repaid[i] = data.dta[i];
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Walk though your code with a debugger, and you will quickly see where your problem lies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a javascript array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
function seperate(data) {
console.log(data)
for (var i = 0; i < data.dta.length; i++) {
       if (data.dta[i].grt === 'GRT') {
            owing.push(data.dta[i]);
            // console.log(owing[i] + i);
       } else {
            repaid.push(data.dta[i])
            // console.log(repaid[i] + i);
       }
   }
}
```

`.push` adds new elements to the end of a given array. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Usage example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.push(4, 5);

console.log(a); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Your current solution creates two arrays, each of length (almost) equal to the input array, but with lots of holes in them. For instance, consider the (simplified) input array as follows:

```
['GRT', 'RPD', 'GRT', 'RPD', 'GRT', 'RPD']
```

Your solution creates two arrays like this:

```
['GRT'    , undefined, 'GRT'    , undefined, 'GRT']
[undefined, 'RPD'    , undefined, 'RPD'    , undefined, 'RPD']
```

Using `push` instead creates two arrays like this:

```
['GRT', 'GRT', 'GRT']
['RPD', 'RPD', 'RPD']
```

Comment: Not my dv, but you could replace the check on 'GRT' with a bit more generic code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is increasing the index independent of the array. So regardless of which array is being updated the index you use for both arrays is incremented by 1.

You can either have separate index variables for each array or you can make use of array [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) functions as shown below.

```
var owing = [];
var repaid = [];
function seperate(data) {
    data.dta.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d.grt === 'GRT') {
            owing.push(d);
        } else {
            repaid.push(d);
        }
    });
}
```